# CMake - Build custom build paths for different configurations

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have a project whose make process generates different build artifacts for each configuration, e.g. if initiated with `make a=a0 b=b0` it would build object files into `builds/a0.b0`, generate a binary `myproject.a0.b0`, and finally update an ambiguous executable link to point to the most recently built project `ln -s myproject.a0.b0 myproject`. For this project, this is a useful feature mainly because:

- It separates the object files for different configurations (so when I rebuild in another configuration I don't have to recompile every single source with new defines and configurations set, (unfortunately) a very common procedure).
- It retains the binaries for each configuration (so it's not required to rebuild to use a different configuration if it has already been built).
- It makes a copy (or link) to the last built binary which is useful in testing.

Right now this is implemented in an ugly decades-old non-portable Makefile. I'd like to reproduce the same behavior in CMake to allow easier building on other platforms but I have not been able to reproduce it in any reasonable manner. It seems like adding targets with add_library/executable, but doing this for each possible permutation of input parameters seems wrong. And I'm not sure I could get the utilization correct, allowing `make`, `make a=a0`, `make b=b0 a=a0` as opposed to what specifying a cmake target would require: `make myproject-a0.b0`.

Is this possible to do in cmake? Namely:

- Specify the build directory based on input parameters.
- Accept the parameters as make arguments which can be left out (defaulted) to select the appropriate target at the level of the makefile (so it's not required to rerun cmake for a new configuration).

Comment: That is true, though don't both support makefiles? (via nmake for the VS case). Granted it might be kind of silly to move over to cmake then artificially limit the build environment... Could you explain to me a bit more about your approach? Is it necessary to specify both -B_builds-AxBx as well as the parameters -DA=Ax -DB=Bx? Is there an option for just `cmake -DA=Ax -DB=Bx` only, followed by whatever build process? (make/VS/Xcode)

Comment: I was referring to me limiting the build environment by going for the make parameters instead of cmake parameters. But yes, the example you gave would require entering in the parameters as well as the build directory, but the latter should be generated so that it's always consistent (and so it's not possible (*easy*) to move away from the established structure). So `cmake -DA=Ax -DB=Bx` and I get a makefile / project file / etc which will build in `builds/project.ax.bx`